# can't enter in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: xubuntu, screen

After I have upgrade to ubuntu 12.04, two days ago, I can't enter. After enter my login the screen shows a message: The system chrashed, one apps actual or former have failed. an then the screen gets in black. Help me, please. Thank you.

Comment: Just reinstall. Why waste time trying to figure what is the problem? stick the CD in, and in few minutes, you'll be done. Always keep your data on a separate disk. I install and uninstall Linux all the time ;)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people have the same problem.

You will need to delete the compiz and compiz-1 directories in your home .config directory and re-boot.  The files will be re-created when you log on.

If you can't get a terminal session on your upgraded system, boot a live CD with Ubuntu and delete the compiz directories on your hard disk; then remove the CD and boot from the hard disk.